# Feed link doesn't work

Tags: stream, feed, publish, facebook-apps

I'm using the Facebook PHP SDK to developp my app.

From this morning, when I publish an automatic post on a user's feed, everything is ok but the link doesn't work anymore... (no reaction on click)
Once the feed is published, the target of the link is "http://www.facebook.com/connect/uiserver.php?app_id=2711...site.com/annonce?a=62&response_type=code&display=page" (and doesn't work)

*I replace the name of my website by mysite.com for this example*

Here is my code :

```
$feed_message = utf8_encode("J&#039;ai besoin de : ".$A_titre);
$feed_picture = "http://www.mysite.com/graph/icon.png";
$feed_link = "http://www.mysite.com/annonce?a=".$ins_id; // go to my website not app
$feed_linkname = utf8_encode($A_titre);
$feed_description = utf8_encode($me_firstname)." a besoin de...";                    
$result = $fb->api('/me/feed/','post',array('message'=>$feed_message,'picture'=>$feed_picture,'link'=>$feed_link,'name'=>$feed_linkname,'description'=>$feed_description));
```

Do you have any idea of what i can do to fix it ?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem. It seems that it's linked to the new "Enhanced Auth Dialog".
I deactivated it since the timeline is not ready anyway, and there's no more http://www.facebook.com/connect/uiserver.php?app_id= appended to the links on the user's wall.

Comment: Ok, this is a beginning, thank you !
But I'd prefer to know the new way to post instead of deactivate something that will be ready in a while... so i'm still looking for a solution, if you find something, let me know !

Comment: I found new elements : actually, the link works BUT only when copy/paste in a new tab or window.
The simple click on the link in the feed doesn't work at all

Comment: Thanks, this helped me for now. You can still use Enhanced Auth Dialog though, just not "Authenticated Referrals". At least, it works for me!